# Does the height of a Van de Graaff generator matter?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields

I'm interested in building a van de Graaff generator as a science project, but when I found some websites that showed how to make one, the height of the housing pipe was tall. If I reduce the height for example from 5 feet to 2 feet, will it play any effect on the overall outcome of the charge formed?

Comment: It will impact (perhaps) the max voltage, but 2 or 3 feet makes a nice one.

Comment: The diameter of the dome determines the voltage that builds up.  You want a height that guarantees that sparks do not spontaneously jump from the dome to the base, and that depends on the voltage of the dome.

Comment: the van de Graaff generator I'm planning to build can generate almost 500,000 volts